# Prove Reverse Fatou's lemma

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**Question**

I am trying to prove the Reverse Fatou's lemma but I can't seem to get it. The statement is the following:

> Suppose that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $g$ an integrable function such that $f_n \leq g$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu (f_n) = \mu ( \limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n)$ where $\mu$ is the integral on a specified measure space.

**Attempt**

We have a sequence $\lbrace f_k \rbrace$ in $\mathbb R$ and $E\subset \mathbb R$. We know that $\limsup f_k = \lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty} g_j$ where $g_j = \sup\limits_{k\geq j } f_k$. Thus we get that
$$f_k \leq g_j \Rightarrow \int_E f_k \leq \int_E g_j \implies \sup\limits_{k\geq j }\int_E f_k \leq \int_E g_j $$
Taking the limit of both sides yields
$$\lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}\sup\limits_{k\geq j }\int_E f_k \leq \lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}\int_E g_j $$
Which is equivalent to
$$\limsup\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}\int_E f_k \leq \liminf\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}\int_E g_j $$

This is where I get stuck. I want to use Fatou's lemma but it won't work in this case. Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: If the $f_k$ are dominated by an integrable function, so are the $g_j$, and the monotone convergence theorem does the rest. If the $f_k$ aren't dominated by an integrable function, $$\limsup \int f_k \leqslant \int \limsup f_k$$ need not hold.

Comment: I thought the Monotone convergence theorem only applies to increasing functions, which we do not have. Is that not true?

Comment: If you have a non-increasing sequence $g_j$ that is dominated by $h$, where $h$is integrable, consider $d_j = h - g_j$. (By the way, you can also directly apply Fatou's lemma to $h - f_k$ if $h$ dominates the $f_k$.)

Comment: I updated the question. Is the second approach better?

Comment: You can't really say much about $\liminf \int g_j - \liminf \int f_k$. It could be positive or negative. If you want to prove $\limsup \int f_k \leqslant \int \limsup f_k$, you must at some point use a hypothesis that guarantees that the inequality actually holds, such as domination of the $f_k$ by an integrable function. Since the inequality need not hold without such an assumption, you can't prove it without.

Comment: Is that not what $f_k \leq g_j$ says? $f_k$ is dominated by the integrable function $g_j$.

Comment: How do you know that $g_j$ is integrable?

Comment: Lets say I have $f_k \leq f$ where $f$ is integrable, I still don't see how to move forward.

Comment: Then let $h_k = f - f_k$. Fatou: $\int \liminf h_k \leqslant \liminf \int h_k$. Expanding $h_k$: $\int (f - \limsup f_k) \leqslant \int f - \limsup \int f_k$, or subtracting the finite quantity $\int f$, $-\int \limsup f_k \leqslant -\limsup \int f_k \iff \limsup \int f_k \leqslant \int \limsup f_k$.

Comment: So are you saying that $\liminf f_k = \limsup f_k$ because $f_k$ is bounded above by $f$? I thought that only applied if the limit existed.

Comment: No. I'm saying $\liminf (-f_k) = - \limsup f_k$.

Comment: Sorry to be commeting on this old post , but can u give me some clearance why $ lim inf(−fk)=−lim supfk$ ?

Comment: @Someone These are real numbers. Why not start by drawing a picture and then applying the definitions?

Answer (score 2):

As $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $g$ are both measurable, we know that $(g-f_n)$ is also measurable.

Therefore by Fatou's Lemma

$$\mu (\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} (g-f_n)) \leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(g-f_n) \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space(1)$$

As the function $g$ is independent of $n$, we can rewrite $(1)$ as the following (by linearity of the integral)

$$ \mu (g) + \mu(\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} (-f_n)) \leq \mu(g)+ \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} (-\mu(f_n))\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (2)$$

We can immediately observe that $\mu (g)$ is present on both sides of the inequality which allows us to simplify to the following result:

$$ \mu(\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} (-f_n)) \leq  \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} (-\mu(f_n))\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (3)$$

We now complete the proof by using the fact that $\liminf _{n\rightarrow \infty} (-f_n) = - \limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} (f_n)$ and substituting this into $(3)$ to deduce

$$ -\mu(\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty}(f_n)) \leq  -\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} (\mu(f_n))\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space (4)$$

And by rearranging inequality $(4)$ above, we get the final result:

$$ \fbox{$\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} (\mu(f_n)) \space \leq \space \mu(\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty}(f_n))$} $$

*Note: as discussed in the comments, equality does not hold here unless the limit exists and the hypotheses for monotone convergence are satisfied*

Comment: Thanks for nice derivation.  Is the other direction obvious so that you can make it an equality  ? If so, not to me. Thanks.

Comment: The other direction is not true in general, so we cannot make this an equality. By the Monotone Converhence Theorem if the limit exists, then we have equality. But we can’t guarantee that the limit is defined @markleeds

Comment: It's much appreciated.